# Match multiple url paths with regex including forward slash

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to match 3 possible paths with regex, but I struggle to match it including the forward slash.

```js
const pathRegex = '(user|artist|album):/\//';
const createRegex = new RegExp(pathRegex, 'i');

console( createRegex.test('user/')  );
```

Comment: So use `const pathRegex = '(user|artist|album):/'` (with or without `:` - no idea if it should be there)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to escape the forward slash in the RegExp constructor.

Just use

```
const pathRegex = '(user|artist|album)/';
                                      ^
```

**NOTE:** If there are no special characters and nothing to escape, and if there are many forward slashes, the `RegExp` constructor notation looks much cleaner than a literal regex notation.

So, here, you can also use this literal regex notation:

```
/(user|artist|album)\//i.test("user/")
                    ^^
```

Demo:

```js
const pathRegex = '(user|artist|album)/';
const createRegex = new RegExp(pathRegex, 'i');
document.body.innerHTML = createRegex.test("user/") + "<br/>";
document.body.innerHTML += /(user|artist|album)\//i.test("user/");
```

Comment: And better with regex literal  than constructor

Comment: @Tushar: I know, but in some cases, when there are no special characters and nothing to escape, but there are many forward slashes, the RegExp constructor notation looks much cleaner.